# Как сделать кнопку с функциональностью ссылки (html)

Tags: html, django, angularjs

Понимаю, что это азы и должно быть очень просто.

вот кусок кода с ошибкой:

```
<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="s_button"
       window.open('{% url 'online_sc' %}', '_blank');>
</div>
```

Подскажите, как создать кнопку в `.html` с GET-запросом при открытии ссылки в отдельном окне или как сделать так, что бы при нажатии на кнопку выполнилось следующее:  `window.open('{% url 'online_sc' %}', '_blank')`?

Comment: что значит _запуск другого html-файла_?

Comment: _эту строку я перенес с другой страницы, на которой она работала._ - просто сравни как вызывалась это строку в файле где она работала и как ты вызываешь ее сейчас

Comment: @Grundy - при нажатии на кнопку в браузере должна появляться новая вкладка с информацией из этого "другого html-файла"

Comment: @Grundy - на другой странице использовался вызов функции. Мне же не нужно создавать для одной строки отдельную функцию и ее вызывать. А как без использования функции я еще не знаю.

Comment: непонятно причем тут ангуляр. _Мне же не нужно создавать для одной строки отдельную функцию и ее вызывать._ - почему нет? сначала нужно сделать чтобы заработало, а только потом уже смотреть как можно улучшить.

Comment: @Grundy - потому что это больше кода. У меня задание было как раз не использовать функцию, а прописать в кнопке одной строчкой кода.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51939/discussion-between-grundy-and-emptyman).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь @Grundy!
Как оказалось, все действительно просто.

@Grundy:

> на самом деле не хватает просто onclick атрибута у кнопки.

В результате у меня получилось запустить данный код переписав его до следующего вида:

```
<div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="s_button"
       onclick="window.open('{% url 'online_air_schedule' %}', '_blank')"
</div>
```